# Repository Entity not found in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing two projects with Symfony2, and I began to code the second project and I'm facing some problems with Custom functions to search in my tables.

**This is my Sites Entity**

```
namespace Ad\SisBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Sites
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sites")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ad\SisBundle\Entity\SitesRepository")
 */
class Sites
{
```

**This is my SitesRepository Entity**

```
namespace Ad\SisBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SitesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
```

The problem is that I can't access any function that I create in my SitesRepository

I was dumping the doctrine EntityRepository Class and I saw this.

```
EntityRepository {#309 ▼
  #_entityName: "Ad\SisBundle\Entity\Sites"
  #_em: EntityManager {#289 …10}
  #_class: ClassMetadata {#298 ▼
    +name: "Ad\SisBundle\Entity\Sites"
    +namespace: "Ad\SisBundle\Entity"
    +rootEntityName: "Ad\SisBundle\Entity\Sites"
    +customGeneratorDefinition: null
    +customRepositoryClassName: null
    +isMappedSuperclass: false
    +parentClasses: []
    +subClasses: []
    +namedQueries: []
    +namedNativeQueries: []
    +sqlResultSetMappings: []
    +identifier: array:1 [▶]
    +inheritanceType: 1
    +generatorType: 4
    +fieldMappings: array:5 [▶]
    +fieldNames: array:5 [▶]
    +columnNames: array:5 [▶]
    +discriminatorValue: null
    +discriminatorMap: []
    +discriminatorColumn: null
    +table: array:1 [▶]
    +lifecycleCallbacks: []
    +entityListeners: []
    +associationMappings: []
    +isIdentifierComposite: false
    +containsForeignIdentifier: false
    +idGenerator: IdentityGenerator {#306 ▶}
    +sequenceGeneratorDefinition: null
    +tableGeneratorDefinition: null
    +changeTrackingPolicy: 1
    +isVersioned: null
    +versionField: null
    +reflClass: ReflectionClass {#307 ▶}
    +isReadOnly: false
    #namingStrategy: DefaultNamingStrategy {#276}
    +reflFields: array:5 [▶]
    -_prototype: null
  }
}
```

So I went to my first project, that is working perfectly, and did the same thing.

```
ScheduleRepository {#1931 ▼
  #_entityName: "ApplicationBundle\Entity\Schedule"
  #_em: EntityManager {#137 …10}
  #_class: ClassMetadata {#1825 ▼
    +name: "ApplicationBundle\Entity\Schedule"
    +namespace: "ApplicationBundle\Entity"
    +rootEntityName: "ApplicationBundle\Entity\Schedule"
    +customGeneratorDefinition: null
    +customRepositoryClassName: "ApplicationBundle\Entity\ScheduleRepository"
    +isMappedSuperclass: false
    +parentClasses: []
    +subClasses: []
    +namedQueries: []
    +namedNativeQueries: []
    +sqlResultSetMappings: []
    +identifier: array:1 [▶]
    +inheritanceType: 1
    +generatorType: 4
    +fieldMappings: array:3 [▶]
    +fieldNames: array:3 [▶]
    +columnNames: array:3 [▶]
    +discriminatorValue: null
    +discriminatorMap: []
    +discriminatorColumn: null
    +table: array:2 [▶]
    +lifecycleCallbacks: array:2 [▶]
    +entityListeners: []
    +associationMappings: array:2 [▶]
    +isIdentifierComposite: false
    +containsForeignIdentifier: false
    +idGenerator: IdentityGenerator {#1852 ▶}
    +sequenceGeneratorDefinition: null
    +tableGeneratorDefinition: null
    +changeTrackingPolicy: 1
    +isVersioned: null
    +versionField: null
    +reflClass: ReflectionClass {#1840 ▶}
    +isReadOnly: false
    #namingStrategy: DefaultNamingStrategy {#119}
    +reflFields: array:5 [▶]
    -_prototype: null
  }
}
```

In my Schedule Entity from project #1 I have the **customRepositoryClassName** filled, but in my Sites Entity not. Why? The both use the same version of doctrine and symfony.

---

I saw that the dump in project #1 is dumping *ScheduleRepository* and project #2 is dumping *EntityRepository*. Maybe this is the problem?

Project #1 dump:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
dump( $em->getRepository( "ApplicationBundle:Schedule" ) );exit;
```

Project #2 dump:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
dump( $em->getRepository( "AdSisBundle:Sites" ) );exit;
```

---

The entities from project #2 was created using: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

That is the only difference between the both projects.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Look under Resource/config/doctrine in the non-working project.  I'm guessing that you find some orm files which you generated at some point and forgot about.  They will override your annotations.

Comment: Perfect @Cerad, I did that and it work. I remove all the files orm.xml and my Entity was found. Thank you